# Обозначения специальных клавиш в Linux

Tags: linux, hotkeys

После перехода с windows-систем крайне непривычно видеть обозначения клавиш с Ctrl, Alt и других.

Например, в mc команда `chown` это C-x o -- поисле недолгих поисков понимаешь, что это сочетание клавиш Ctrl-x o.

А что за сочетание такое M-? (`Find file` в mc) и как его набирать?

Или другой пример, из [tmux](http://man.openbsd.org/tmux):

> M-1 to M-5 Arrange panes in one of the five preset layouts:
>   even-horizontal, even-vertical, main-horizontal, main-vertical, or
>   tiled.

Вообще, какие обозначения приняты в linux для таких специальных клавиш, типа <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_(%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

наиболее старое упоминание таких сокращений нашёл в исходниках [*gnu emacs* версии 18.59](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tag/?h=emacs-18.59), которая [вышла 25 лет назад](https://www.jwz.org/doc/emacs-timeline.html). цитата из `man/emacs.texi`:

```
You can use modifier keys such as @key{CTRL}, @key{META} and @key{SHIFT}
with function keys.  To represent these modifiers, prepend the strings
@samp{C-}, @samp{M-} and @samp{S-} to the symbol name.
```

но, конечно, такое сокращение широко употреблялось и ранее. сложно лишь найти достаточно аргументированное подтверждение этому.

---

> А что за сочетание такое M-? (Find file в mc) и как его набирать?

это клавиша <kbd>meta</kbd>, которая может быть представлена [разными способами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_(%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B0)).

нынче это обычно клавиша с надписью `alt`. т.е., надо удерживать <kbd>alt</kbd> и нажать клавишу <kbd>?</kbd>.

но можно и более переносимым образом — через клавишу <kbd>escape</kbd>: нажать и отпустить её, а затем нажать клавишу <kbd>?</kbd>.